# Connecting to an existing docker postgres container with sequelize

Tags: postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I have an existing postgres container that is working fine on its own. I am trying to follow best practices with Sequelize with proper migrations and models now.
I spin up the docker container containing the postgres database:

```
Starting postgres-express-docker_postgres_1 ... done
Attaching to postgres-express-docker_postgres_1
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | 2020-08-06 14:43:59.373 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1  | 2020-08-06 14:43:59.373 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-08-06 14:43:59.373 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-08-06 14:43:59.376 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2020-08-06 14:43:59.388 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-06 14:43:54 UTC
postgres_1  | 2020-08-06 14:43:59.393 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Then when I try to run sequelize db:migrate to run the built out migrations I get:

```
ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 0.0.0.0:5432
```

What Am I missing here? The sequelize Config is pointing to the same address...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you exposing the port 5432 in your Postgres container?

Comment: Yes. When I run the server and make post requests using postman it works